# Height of ideal $(xz,yz,xt,yt)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

This may be elementary. I want to calculate height of ideal $I=(xz,yz,xt,yt)$ in polynomial ring $k[x,y,z,t]$ in which k is a field.

From KPIT I know $\operatorname{ht}I\leq\operatorname{ht}(x,y)=2$. Honestly I tried to find a nonzero prime ideal which is a subset of $I$, but I failed, and it isn't necessarily true anyway.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $(xz-yt)$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Damn. That is awesome

Comment: You say "and it isnt necessarily true anyway" but you should believe your geometric intuition. The vanishing set of that ideal is obviously not three-dimensional (once you choose one variable non-zero, two others are automatically fixed at zero), so the ideal cannot have height one.

Comment: Anyway, if it had height $1$, it would be contained in a principal prime since $k[x,y,z,t]$ is a UFD.

Comment: $\operatorname{ht}I=\min\operatorname{ht}P$ where $P$ runs through the minimal primes over $I$. It's easily seen that these are $(x,y)$, and $(z,t)$. So the height is $2$. No need to find any non-zero prime contained in $I$.